# Sitecore JSS nextjs | The requested document was not found

Tags: jss, graphql, nextjs, layout-service, rendering-host

Sitecore jss nextjs sample app in connected mode.

installation is done as per https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/200/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--creating-a-jss-next-js-application-with-the-jss-initializer.html

On browsing https://appname.dev.local it gets redirected to https://appname.dev.local/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx
[image]

layout service - ok
[image]

Experience editor - ok
[image]

localhost:3000 - ok
[image]

What may have gone wrong ?

If I open any wrong url, say https://appname.dev.local/sit, then it opens blank page with header
[image]

Comment: what are you expecting on the root of your CM instance?

Comment: @RichardSeal Home page as per config file under sitecore\config\appname.config

 <site patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            inherits="website"
            name="appname"
            hostName="appname.dev.local"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/appname"
            startItem="/home"
            database="master" />

Comment: Also, in show config, I can see it in sites and apps

Comment: What is routing the traffic from appname.dev.local to localhost:3000 ?

Comment: Looks like we can not run sitecore nextjs app in integrated mode in local environment. @RichardSeal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we cannot run sitecore nextjs app in integrated mode in local environment.  That is why it was not working.